# Configure Mocha Test Runner in Bamboo

Tags: mocha.js, bamboo

I've configured and am executing mocha tests in WebStorm, so I know the module is working properly. But I can't seem to make it run from a Bamboo task. The task runs with *Success* but there are 0 tests executed.

This is my configuration atm:
[image]

`app/` is my working dir. Tried also with `app/node_modules/mocha/bin/` and other possibilities. I am not sure which exactly is the Mocha executable of all the `mocha` named files in the module...

Or maybe the problem lies in the tests dir? I've got test files, respectively in `app/test/unit/models/` and `app/test/unit/services/`. But in WebStorm I configured it with the general test dir - just `/app/test`. Configuring the Mocha task in Bamboo with the specific test folders did not yield result...

I believe the problem comes from wrong directory configurations in the task, but I've tried writing whatever paths already and I've got no idea what's missing or wrong...

Comment: did you added "Mocha Test Parser " task for the Bamboo? So the results of your tests are read by Bamboo and displayed properly in Bamboo UI.

Comment: @Borys, the problem is that no tests are ran at the first place. But yes, I do have `Test Parser` in the tasks queue. But it fails because there are no test results found, to be read.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed from your screenshot that the "Parse test results produced by this task" box isn't checked.  This is what tells Bamboo to parse the output of the tests that you run.